# How to toggle CSS styles with Toggle method in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

This is Header component with React-Bootstrap. I created a menu icon with pure CSS but I want to change the icon function onClick but I'm getting the error - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined` . It's there any way I'm getting it wrongly? Kindly check. Thanks.

Also, it's there a way, I can handle this with React Hooks method instead?

Thanks.

```
import styles from './Landing.module.css';
import './Landing.module.css';;

const openMenu = (open) => {
    open.classList.toggle('change');
};

 <Nav className="ml-auto">
  <div className={styles.allMenus}>
    <div className="menuIcon" onClick={openMenu}>
       <div className={styles.bar1}></div>
         <div className={styles.bar2}></div>
           <div className={styles.bar3}></div>
         </div>
      </div>
 </Nav>
```

My CSS - It has the change styles

```
div[class="menuIcon"] {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 13px;
    margin-right: 46px;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 32px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}
  
.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}
  
.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}
```

Comment: `className="menuIcon"` is that how classNames are declared?! In standard HTML, its simply `class="my_class"`. I would change that... and give it a try. Especially given that it looks like you are trying to use a javascript function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the DOM's `classList` in React, but react JSX elements are not DOM elements, but an XML based markup that is translated to JS.

In React you'll need to use state/props to control the behaviour, and add or remove the classes.

In the example I'm using the `useState()` hook to toggle a boolean, and then I add or remove the class name in the template string.

You can use a library, such as [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) to prevent yourself from writing lots of template strings with class names.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const styles = {
  menuIcon: 'menuIcon',
  change: 'change',
  bar1: 'bar1',
  bar2: 'bar2',
  bar3: 'bar3',
};

const Demo = () => {
  const [changed, setChange] = useState(false);
  
  const openMenu = (open) => {
    setChange(c => !c);
  };

  return (
    <nav className="ml-auto">
      <div className="allMenus">
        <div className={`${styles.menuIcon} ${changed ? styles.change : ''}`} onClick={openMenu}>
          <div className={styles.bar1}></div>
          <div className={styles.bar2}></div>
          <div className={styles.bar3}></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
);
```

```css
.menuIcon {
  padding: 13px;
  margin-right: 46px;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 32px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This works. But in my case, the styles are not getting applied. All the styles didn't work, when I inspected the element, the change got applied to the menu-icon but the styles didn't work with it.

Comment: You are using variables (styles) and not strings. Don't wrap them with quotes.

Comment: Could it be because I'm using className as - `className={styles.theStyleName}`? I'm still not getting it.

Comment: Try changing the className to `className={styles.bar1}` and the rest. I'd have gone with strings but I'm using a CSS framework.

Comment: `styles.allMenus` is a string because that's what className accepts. Try to `console.log(styles)`, and you'll see that it's an object with string properties.

Comment: I've updated the example with mock CSS module styles.

Comment: Working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Please, check this question also [The Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936442/mapping-multiple-array-in-react)